# Extract subparts using pattern matching in Sybase database

Tags: sap-ase

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[\\)\\(\\+\\-\\*\\s]+");

String[] tokens;

try{  tokens = p.split(s); } catch (blah) { }
```

How can I accomplish the above functionality in select statement in Sybase ASE 15.0.3.

The Java class works but we are trying to avoid shuttling data in and out of DBMS.

```
select some_function(column1) from table1
```

I need some suggestion as to how this some_function may be implemented.
REGEXP and SIMILAR TO appear to be useful in the where clause. We want to extract portions of a colum which stores complex expressions.

Thank you

Comment: Please give an example of what you tried so far and describe the error(s) you get.

Comment: using substring, charindex and str_replace, I was able to reduce data from ((US_GDP*100.00)/114.66)*0.1 to US_GDP*100. Solution looks ugly. Still have to reduce it to US_GDP and handle cases when it is 100*US_GDP or 14.35*(US_GDP-5)*00l. Thanks. No errors as I am using functions that I know. I am sure there are other functions. REGEXP and SIMILAR TO are NOT AVAILABLE to me though ASE 15.0.3. Even if they are available they are available only in where clause. I need to extract US_GDP from within a larger formula. Thanks

Comment: Interesting, it might help your cause to describe your input data in more detail as well give some example output. Since with your version of ASE regular expression seems not be well supported a direct translation might be tricky.

Comment: Have you looked at running the Java inside ASE (SQLJ)?  I know some java classes can be installed and run inside the database.

Comment: select PATINDEX("%[*+-/]%",'(ABCDEFG + ABC)') VS select PATINDEX("%[*+-/]%",'(1.00000 + ABC)') Can someone explain why these two select statements return different numbers...  Thank you Lothar/Michael for helpful suggestions. Thanks

Comment: select PATINDEX("%[*+-/]%",'(1.00000 + ABC)') returns 3 whereas  select PATINDEX("%[*+-/]%",'(ABCDEFG + ABC)') returns 10